# Solve the Following System of ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Been stuck on this for a while.
$$dx/dt = 2x+4y+4z$$ 
$$dy/dt = -x-2y $$
$$dz/dt = -x - 2z$$
Where I am so far:
![Where I am][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Vbmk.jpg[image]

Comment: Write it as a matrix system and solve for the eigenvalues, the solution will be in the form of exponentials

Comment: I know the method for solving it, but I cant get the right solution vectors, thank you though :)

Comment: @Moo okay, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, just apply Gaussian elimination to these matrices, you will see, for example, that the first one reduces to the system $$k_1=0$$
$$k_2+k_3=0$$
From this you get $$\vec v_1 =(0,1,-1)^T$$ as the first eigenvector. For the other two, apply the same procedure.